# Setting up line integral of a vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Since a line integral of a vector field is defined as follow:

[image: Since a line integral of a vector field is defined as follow:]

For a problem like this, how do i set up the integral

> Show details to find the work done by the force field $\mathbf{F} =(2x+y)\,\mathbf{i}+x\,\mathbf{j}$
>   in moving an object from $P(1, 1)$ to $Q(4, 3).$

My question is:

1. how to set up the integral for this

   1.1 how to setup the bounds *(a,b)* (what are they)

   1.2 what is **r(t)** and how to find it in this case

Comment: The field is conservative, so you can use the potential function to evaluate.

Comment: This is not substantially different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2782228/265466). Did you not understand the answer that you accepted?

Comment: @amd well, according to my book, they do not really go with the potential function method, they go with the line integral method, that is why i am confused, but now i am sure i understand thanks.

Comment: @amd and it is different because i did not ask how to evaluate this, i asked how to set it up.

Comment: A distinction without a difference. Evaluating a line integral involves “setting up” the equivalent ordinary integral.

Answer (score 2):

You need a vector function that goes over the line for a bound you define, so there's infinite choices. I find it easiest to keep the bound between $[0, 1]$. Our function could be $r(t) = (1 + 3t)i + (1 + 2t)j, 0 < t < 1$

Edit: I misread! They have not specified the path. Instead, one has to recognize the field is conservative, and thus the path $r(t)$ does not matter.

The potential function is given by $Φ(x, y) = x^2 + xy$. If you take the gradient of that, you get $f$. Then, the line integral is given by $Φ(4,3) - Φ(1,1) = 26$

Note that because the path does not matter, we could have carried on with a line and have gotten the same answer.

Comment: i would like to know how you came up with that **r(t)**

Comment: You don’t know that the path is a line segment.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! It's indeed not a line.